# Image move with mouse position - box issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I had originally taken some information from here and expanded on it: onextrapixel.com/examples/interactive-background/index4.html

I have instead incorporated the image to move with mouse position on the page, however there seems to be an issue with there being a top "box" that cuts off some of the hovered image. You can see it in action on a sample page [here](http://jenngaudio.x10host.com/Flower%20Spark/)

My css:

```
.top-image {
    background:url('http://i.imgur.com/wZRaMrB.png');
    position:absolute ;
    top:400px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:0;
   height:100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

My js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var movementStrength = 25;
    var height = movementStrength / $(window).height();
    var width = movementStrength / $(window).width();
    $("body").mousemove(function(e){
        var pageX = e.pageX - ($(window).width() / 2);
        var pageY = e.pageY - ($(window).height() / 2);
        var newvalueX = width * pageX * -1 - 25;
        var newvalueY = height * pageY * -1 - 50;
        $('.top-image').css("background-position", newvalueX+"px     "+newvalueY+"px");
});
});
```

I also hope to repeat this for the right side of the page.

After some suggesting in the comments here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yx1w8ysr/#&togetherjs=D4Q1xTfcaO

Comment: looks like you can try setting the `background-size` to `contain`

Comment: @KingKing I still notice the top being covered, and it made the image 2x the size, I very much appreciate your help though! Have any other ideas?

Comment: it would be better if you provide a simple fiddle demonstrating the problem as well as helping others try editing/making changes before it working as you expect.

Comment: BTW: `background-size: contain` should make the rendered image perfectly inside the element's box. If it's still covered, there must be something strange here. About the size, of course that's the size of your element. Just reduce that fixedly set size to your desired values.

Comment: @KingKing https://jsfiddle.net/yx1w8ysr/#&togetherjs=D4Q1xTfcaO thanks for your help and suggestions! I agree something wacky is going on and I think it is hidden in the Java, I don't know that language too well yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the image's size beforehand, you can set the size of your div fixedly and don't need to use `background-size:contain`. Instead set it to some relative value (less than 100%) so that you have a padding around for the movement of the background image. However if you don't know the size of the image, you should use `background-size:contain` to ensure that your image sits right inside your div container. However with this approach we cannot control the size of the image anymore. That means you cannot use `background-position` to move the image around (because the size fits its parent, moving will cause the image be cut off).

So you need some another wrapper/container and move your inner div (`.top-image`) instead of changing the `background-position`.

Here is the detailed code:

```js
var movementStrength = 25;
var w = $(window).width();
var h = $(window).height();

$(window).mousemove(function(e) {
  var pageX = (e.pageX - w / 2) / w / 2;
  var pageY = (e.pageY - h / 2) / h / 2;
  var newvalueX = pageX * movementStrength;
  var newvalueY = pageY * movementStrength;
  $('.top-image').css({
    left: newvalueX + 'px',
    top: newvalueY + 'px'
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 25px;
  width: 35%;
  height: 35%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
}

.top-image {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/wZRaMrB.png');
  position: absolute;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <div class="top-image"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh wow thank you so much for your time and help! I seriously appreciate it! That fixed it, I would have never gotten it on my own.