# Image hover movement causes overflow on X-axis?

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, overflow

As a followup to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43623477/image-move-with-mouse-position-box-issue/43624842?noredirect=1#comment74298909_43624842), I have attempted to make the hover image on both sides of the page.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4abukmn7/)

JS:

```
var movementStrength = 25;
var w = $(window).width();
var h = $(window).height();

$(window).mousemove(function(e){          
          var pageX = (e.pageX - w / 2) / w / 2;
          var pageY = (e.pageY - h / 2) / h / 2;
          var newvalueX = pageX * movementStrength;
          var newvalueY = pageY * movementStrength;          
          $('.top-image-left').css({ left: newvalueX + 'px', top: newvalueY + 'px'});
});


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class='top-contain-left'>
      <div class="top-image-left">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='top-contain-right'>
      <div class="top-image-right"></div>
    </div>
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='top-contain-left'>
  <div class="top-image-left">
  </div>
</div>

<div class='top-contain-right'>
  <div class="top-image-right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.top-contain-left {
  padding: 25px;
  width: 35%;
  height: 35%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
}

.top-image-left {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/wZRaMrB.png');
  position: absolute;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


.top-contain-right {
  padding:25px;
  width:35%;
  height:35%;
  position:absolute;
  top:400px;
  right: -20%;
}


.top-image-right {
  background:url('http://i.imgur.com/Qn6xkCZ.png');
  position:absolute ;
  background-size: contain;
  width:100%;
  z-index:0;
  height:100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;  
}
```

You will notice there is an overflow on the right side. (Can't upload more than 2 links at this time)

You can also view it on my website `http://jenngaudio.x10host.com/Flower%20Spark/`

I have tried `overflow-x: hidden` property but it causes issues for the entire page - probably because I am using a responsive skeleton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right padding is caused by the default `background-position` which is `left top`. The image's width is smaller than the container div's width so you see the right padding. To solve this problem, just align the background image to right using `background-position: right top`. Also you should apply `overflow-x:hidden` to the `body` to prevent the horizontal scrollbar from appearing and disappearing  while moving the mouse. And finally I fixed your script a bit to use just 1 `window.onmousemove` handler. You don't need 2 handlers because you use the same calculated values to update the positions of 2 images (even in case you need different values, just performance different calculations in that same handler).

Here is the updated code:

```js
var movementStrength = 25;
var w = $(window).width();
var h = $(window).height();

$(window).mousemove(function(e){          
          var pageX = (e.pageX - w / 2) / w / 2;
          var pageY = (e.pageY - h / 2) / h / 2;
          var newvalueX = pageX * movementStrength;
          var newvalueY = pageY * movementStrength;          
          $('.top-image-left').css({ left: newvalueX + 'px', top: newvalueY + 'px'});
          $('.top-image-right').css({ right: newvalueX + 'px', top: newvalueY + 'px'});
});
```

```css
.top-contain-left {
  padding: 25px;
  width: 35%;
  height: 35%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
}

.top-image-left {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/wZRaMrB.png');
  position: absolute;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


.top-contain-right {
  padding:25px;
  width:35%;
  height:35%;
  position:absolute;
  top:400px;
  right: 0%;  
}


.top-image-right {
  background:url('http://i.imgur.com/Qn6xkCZ.png') right top;
  position:absolute ;
  background-size: contain;
  width:100%;
  z-index:0;
  height:100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;  
  right:0px;  
}
body {
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='top-contain-left'>
  <div class="top-image-left">
  </div>
</div>

<div class='top-contain-right'>
  <div class="top-image-right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks yet again for the help and righting my wrong with the js, I'm not very familiar with it yet and I will keep that in mind with the handle from now on!